# Expresso tutorials

Tags: node.js

I have found virtually no documentation other than the [official one](http://visionmedia.github.com/expresso/) dealing with the JavaScript TDD framework written for nodejs called Expresso. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I learned Expresso mainly by looking at the source for [js-traverse](https://github.com/substack/js-traverse). It's a good example because:

- It has a lot of tests
- It's for a fairly simple library
- Its `package.json` set up properly. It includes expresso as a devDependency so it will get installed when running `npm install .`, and it includes a test script so its tests can be run with `npm test`.

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks - I was wondering if there was a pragma for doing that.

Comment: This answer is out of date. js-traverse is no longer using Express, seems to now use tape (which I believe is built on top of Tap https://github.com/isaacs/node-tap)

Comment: The question is out of date too. I'm not sure why it's getting visitors. If you're looking for a test framework for node, please look at Mocha.

Answer (score 2):

There's a video tutorial on [nodetuts.com](http://nodetuts.com) covering Expresso and Should.js

http://vimeo.com/19763028

**Edit:** updated to the link to point to Vimeo.

Comment: Thanks @rodrigo-silveira; it looks like it's been removed. I found the screencast on Vimeo, however. I hope that helps